# Accessibility issue with p:select

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accessibility

Using primefaces 5.1, i'm testing my app with [WCAG validator](http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) and the following code is breaking a guideline:

```
<p:outputLabel for="selectHowMuch" value="Do you feel edgy lately ?" />

<p:selectOneMenu id="selectHowMuch" value="Yes">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Argggg" itemValue="3" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="hmmm" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="NO!" itemValue="0" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

the broken guideline is

> Success Criteria 1.3.1 Info and Relationships (A) Check 91: select
>   element missing an associated label.
>
> Repair: Add a label element that surrounds the control's label. Set
>   the for attribute on the label element to the same value as the id
>   attribute of the control. And/or add a title attribute to the input
>   element. And/or create a label element that contains the input
>   element.

Error Line 1, Column 16711:

```
<select id="_testapp_WAR_testapp001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input"
```

Note that the p:outputLabel actually did help (if i remove it, i get more errors), but it looks like it's not covering the `<select>` _input label

I also noticed that the same happens for other select components.
Any ideas to get around this ?

Edit: here's my generated code:

```
<label  id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:j_idt62"  class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
    for="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_focus">Do you feel edgy lately ?</label>

<div id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input
            id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_focus"
            name="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_focus"
            type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <select
            id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input"
            name="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input"
            tabindex="-1"><option value="3">Argggg</option>
            <option value="2">Yes</option>
            <option value="1">hmmm</option>
            <option value="0">NO!</option></select>
    </div>
    <label
        id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_label"
        class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label>
    <div
        class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
    </div>
    <div
        id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_panel"
        class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow">
        <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper"
            style="height: auto">
            <ul
                class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
                <li
                    class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
                    data-label="Argggg">Argggg</li>
                <li
                    class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
                    data-label="Yes">Yes</li>
                <li
                    class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
                    data-label="hmmm">hmmm</li>
                <li
                    class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
                    data-label="NO!">NO!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_s"
    type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("SelectOneMenu","widget__tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT__j_idt3_selectHowMuch",{id:"_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch",widgetVar:"widget__tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT__j_idt3_selectHowMuch"})});</script>
```

Comment: can you show the generated code of the label?

Comment: Test PrimeFaces trunk or latest elite release. Lots of improvements since tge 5.1 community release.

Comment: @yannicuLar there is nothing wrong with your code except for that it might not work in IE (especially older IE versions) because of the colons in the ids. The label association is correct. It looks like the WCAG validator you are using also has a bug related to IDs with colons in them.

Comment: What is the intent of the `<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">`?

Comment: Not sure,what it does, it's auto-generated html content. Do you think it's relevant to the validation issue?

Comment: I think that as @Adam pointed out, the problem comes from the fact that the `<select>` element with id = `_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input` has no label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, i have to contrast with the last answer...

In your example, this select does not have an associated label

```
 <select
        id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input"
        name="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_input"
        tabindex="-1"><option value="3">Argggg</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
        <option value="1">hmmm</option>
        <option value="0">NO!</option></select>
```

There is one label after it who might have been thought for it, but it does not have a `for` attribute and does not contain the `select` tag.

```
 <label
    id="_tutorial_WAR_tutorial001SNAPSHOT_:j_idt3:selectHowMuch_label"
    class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label>
```

As I understand, both the `input` and the `select` are generated for this one field and only one label is correctly associated with the `input`. This looks like a bug in primefaces, and you should ask their staff to make some corrections...

Also there would be more correction to do, because the first label should be associated with the select element, and the input element be invisible to screenreaders if I correctly understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your markup per se. It conforms to one of the accepted techniques.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/H44#H44-ex1

Although that example shows use with an `<input>` element, it is equally valid with a `<select>` element.

This looks like a bug in your validator. I suggest trying FireEyes http://www.deque.com/products/fireeyes/fireeyes-installation/